# Why does my query, when executed in PHP, add an extra space?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, rendering

I have sat up a simple Curl to navigate to a page, and save the result in a string. The goal is to get a adress from the page (wrapped in a specific html tag), and then save that to a database on my server

```
$url = "http://www.odensebolig.dk/property/vindegade-128-lejl-nr-115-5000-odense-c/";
$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.dk");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then i find a adress between 2 html-tags and save that result in a variable. Example: "Vindegade 128, lejl. nr. 115, 5000 Odense C". I've found a function here on stackoverflow i use for this. Then i split the string into array with adress, zip, and town, and finaly make a query updating the adress in my adresses table:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

//To get the full adress i do this
$full_adress = get_string_between($result, '<h4>', '</h4>');
//And the result:
echo $full_adress; //Vindegade 128, lejl. nr. 115, 5000 Odense C

//Find last comma
$last_comma = strrpos($full_adress, ',');
//Save all text before last comma
//And here i have tried removing all kinds of line breaks, and trim trailing and endeing spaces
$adress['adress'] = preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", trim(substr($full_adress, 0, $last_comma)));
$adress['zip'] = substr($full_adress, ($last_comma + 2), 4);
$adress['town'] = substr($full_adress, ($last_comma + 7));
//And the result of [adresse]:
echo $adress['adress']; //Vindegade 128, lejl. nr. 115
//I then put the info in a query
$query = "UPDATE adresses SET `adress` = '". $adress['adress'] ."' WHERE `url` = '$url'";
//Go!
if($objCon->query($query)){
    echo 'Done';//Done
}
```

Now the strange thing is that in my adresses table, the record for the url is becoming: "Vindegade  128, lejl. nr. 115" (With a extra space between "Vindegade" and "128"). Why? If i instead echo out my query, and manually insert it into phpmyadmin, the record is not updated with the extra space

Comment: It might be a tab in the source HTML.

Comment: Sounds unlikely. I would expect the database to be populated with a literal "(array)" using the code above since your treating an array as a string.

Comment: without seeing the source HTML data, this is going to be very tricky to work out. And symcbean's point is also correct. Is this your real code?

Comment: No its just an example code. I have corrected the error in the above code

Comment: can we have the relevant HTML please? If you're saying that data is not saved as per the original version, then we need to see the original version

Comment: Here is an example url: http://www.odensebolig.dk/property/vindegade-128-lejl-nr-115-5000-odense-c/ (Sorry for late answer)

Comment: that doesn't contain the sample data in the question, which makes it a bit hard to diagnose the problem - we don't know what part you're intending to read, and whether it contains the same issue. Also please paste the (relevant) HTML in to the question itself - external links can change or die over time. The question should stand or fall by itself - thanks.

Comment: I have updated the code again^^

Comment: There is a typo / syntax error in your `$query = ...` line.  There is no way that this code even runs.

Comment: Ok thanks, but still please paste the target HTML as well, for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original HTML

```
<h4>Vindegade  128, lejl. nr. 115, 5000 Odense C</h4>
```

copied straight from the page you linked to contains two spaces already in the location you mentioned (between "Vindegade" and "128"). Since I've used the formatted code display to show the raw string, you can see the space.

Whereas if I paste it directly, for the browser to interpret and render the HTML, as below, you can't, even though it's there in the HTML source.

---

Vindegade  128, lejl. nr. 115, 5000 Odense C

---

So, if, as you described, you echoed that original HTML out into a web page using PHP, and then copied/pasted that output from your browser into another program (such as phpMyAdmin), then that would explain the difference. Browsers generally will only display the first of any set of consecutive spaces in raw HTML, so the version you copied will have been stripped of its second space (by the browser's rendering engine) already before you ran the query, whereas the version sent to mySQL direct from your PHP will not have had that treatment.

To summarise, what you're experiencing is simply a side-effect of the way browsers treat spaces in HTML documents.

N.B. If you paste the two example strings above from your browser window into a text editor you'll also see the difference.